# how to send different push notifications from python server to multiple android devices?

Tags: android, python, push-notification

We have a python script which do specific job and we want when it see the trigger occurred , it sends a push notification to android devices 
but we don't want to send a default message to all of our users.
we want to send customize message based on the trigger to our users 
for example :

```
"user1" the "trigger" hits.
"user2" the "trigger" hits.
```

.
.
can you help me how to send different messages to different unique android IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you're familiar with GCM (official documentation for start you could find here [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Now regarding your question: 
you have to have storage on your server where you save registration id, device token + any info which will help you to differ one user/device from another. For example, I did same thing for different apps and stored package_name in addition.

To send custom message you'll need:

1) choose to which devices/users you'll send a message (on exit you'll have a list of device tokens)

2) get list of registration ids from device tokens (on exit list of registration ids)
I separated 1 and 2 for simplicity.

3) I suggest that you know that GCM supports for up to 1,000 recipients for a single message. So you should form here a string of registration ids separated by comma. If you need to send message to 2500 devices, you need to do 3 requests.

4) send request to GCM server and see custom message on specific devices. 
Regards.

Comment: thanks for your response ,  but i have another question . our app needs to check for new messages once in a day , which one of Pull or Push based configuration do you prefer ?

Comment: Welcome.  You could store messages you sent via push on the server side. And by request from mobile end (by package name, device token, time period) provide all or new messages which are being sent for specific device for specific period of time. Actually flexibility is great: on mobile end you could add listeners for events you want to handle. Once they occur notify server about it. On the server side you could create a service which monitor changes, do specific job by time, etc.